# How do I get rid of these mesh seams?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh

The objects look fine in rendered view, but once I render out the frames these seams appear. Super subtle but want to get rid of them. Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell from the photos, but the bottom makes it look like you might have some duplicate faces.Try select-all > mesh > clean-up > merge-by-distance. The only other thing I see, (and again, it's hard to tell), is it looks like your mesh contains lots of long, stretched, triangles. Those are notorious for rendering/lighting issues. That's just my best guess.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately that didn't work. If you know of anything else, please let me know! I went through all of the clean up options and nothing made the change.